# How do I hide title text in application?

Tags: android

In my app I am using a logo instead of an icon at the top using android:logo="@drawable/logo" in  in the manifest file. The only problem is that the title text of the application still shows up next to it. I have seen some solutions, but none that can be done with my current API minimum of 5 which I am wanting to keep. How do I do so? And please don't suggest setting android:label="" as many suggested in other similar questions, as this makes the launcher icon not have a label as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your activity `onCreate`

```
setTitle("");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:
use in onCreate:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

This will hide your icon and title. Now add one linear or relative layout containing only icon above other elements in your layout files.